# getting an error when i try to run Sqlite3 new installation

Tags: sqlite

i just installed sqlite3 from the source provided on their official website, i downloaded the file 'sqlite-autoconf-3071201.tar.gz' and compiled it.

but when i try to run sqlite from the commandline, i get the following message:

> SQLite header and source version mismatch 
>   2011-11-01 00:52:41 c7c6050ef060877ebe77b41d959e9df13f8c9b5e 
>   2012-05-22 02:45:53 6d326d44fd1d626aae0e8456e5fa2049f1ce0789

i am using ubuntu most recent version.

can anybody help with this? thanks

Comment: Did you compile by only updating the source file? You should use both, source file and header as they are in the download. They both know which version they belong to and make sure that they are not compiled in wrong combinations. I wonder however why it did not already provoke a compiler error...